# Joomla htmlhelper how to write <image> tag nested into <a> tag

Tags: php, joomla

I'm customizing the output of a Joomla 4 content component.
I wrote an override in Joomla template but I have an issue writing the correct html string usign htmlhelper api.

This is the final html I need:

```
<div class="row">
    <a href="images/big/768.jpg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="example-gallery" class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="images/small/600.jpg" class="img-fluid">
    </a>
    <a href="images/big/769.jpg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="example-gallery" class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="images/small/601.jpg" class="img-fluid">
    </a>
    <a href="images/big/770.jpg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="example-gallery" class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="images/small/602.jpg" class="img-fluid">
    </a>
</div>
```

I wrote this code, where $customFields['photos']->rawvalue is an array that contains the list of images filenames

```
<div class="row">
    <?php
        foreach($customFields['photos']->rawvalue as $foto) { ?>
            <?php 
                echo HTMLHelper::_('link', 'images/fiera/big/'.$foto, '', ["class" => "col-sm-6 col-md-4", "data-toggle" => "lightbox", "data-gallery" => "fiera"]);
                echo HTMLHelper::_('image', 'images/fiera/small/'.$foto, $foto, ["class" => "img-fluid"], false, 0); 
            ?>  
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

The problem is that in this way the  tag is not inside  tag; the actual autput is this:

```
<div class="row">
    <a href="/images/fiera/big/10_fiera_big.jpg" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="fiera"></a><img class="img-fluid" src="/images/fiera/small/10_fiera_big.jpg" alt="10_fiera_big.jpg">                        
    <a href="/images/fiera/big/11_fiera_big.jpg" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="fiera"></a><img class="img-fluid" src="/images/fiera/small/11_fiera_big.jpg" alt="11_fiera_big.jpg">                            
</div>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="row">
    <?php foreach ($customFields['photos']->rawvalue as $foto) : ?>
        <?php echo HTMLHelper::_('link', HTMLHelper::_('image', 'images/fiera/small/'.$foto, $foto, ['class' => 'img-fluid'], false, 0), 'images/fiera/big/'.$foto, ['class' => 'col-sm-4', 'data-toggle' => 'lightbox', 'data-gallery' => 'fiera']); ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```